# How to write HttpChunkedInput / ChunkedStream?

Tags: java, netty

I have the following code that works perfect:

```
sendHeaders(obj)
setChunked()
sendRequestMessage()

context.write(DefaultFileRegion(obj.file, 0L, obj.file.length()))
context.writeAndFlush(LastHttpContent.EMPTY_LAST_CONTENT)
```

But if I send

```
context.writeAndFlush(HttpChunkedInput(ChunkedStream(obj.stream().buffered())))
```

then I get `UnsupportedOperationExcpetion` because HttpChunkedInput is not suported. But there are many examples (at least `HttpStaticFileServerHandler`) so they do the same and it works. Why?

Comment: Compare your pipeline config with the working examples, and [edit] your post to include this pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just forgot to add `ChunkedWriteHandler` to the pipeline

```
addLast("streamer", ChunkedWriteHandler())
```

Comment: I heard the same issue and this saved my time. Thanks !